# ACPI Error: Could not disable RealTimeClock events

Tags: startup, acpi

Trying to install Ubuntu 22.04 it went through the setup just fine but when prompted to restart it does fine but when it tries to launch it goes to the attached image saying:

```
ACPI Error: Could not disable RealTimeClock events
```

This is on a Microsoft Surface laptop 5. I am now able to get past the error and start the GUI, but on boot, the error is still present.

[image: image of the error]

Comment: I think the ACPI Error might not be the problem that is causing your keyboard issues. Are you able to update the question with more details of your hardware (laptop model etc)?

Comment: acpi notices during boot are benign. Those are notifications your bios tells the kernel incorrect info.